# Android development SDK Sharing

Tags: android, ide

I just want to know if there is a way to share Android SDK in multiple systems. Suppose if we have 500 computers in the workspace for Android development, do we need to install android SDK , eclipse etc. in all of them? Or is there a Domain Controller kind of thing? Or atleast copy Android SDK some where in the network and use it?

Comment: The SDK can be in a network drive, you just need to link to its location from Eclipse. Every computer will need Eclipse or whatever IDE you use.

Comment: @Leco thats what i thought. But not sure if that can be done

Comment: Alternatively, you can write the code in a "notepad" or text editor and then use the Android tools from the SDK to compile the app. But the code will be much harder to debug if you are not using an IDE.

Comment: @Leco Its not about debugging. Even typing is difficult. When I start typing a word, Eclipse prompts me with the hints and I select one one of them. So, I can't do it in notepad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Android SDK can be loaded to a network share and accessed by multiple users. Just put the SDK on server or in one PC on the network. Then, point your IDE to the network path where you have copied the SDK.

This screenshot should give you an idea of how to set the path to your SDK in Eclipse.

[image: Screenshot of setting an SDK network path in Eclipse]

**NOTE:**

Doing this will decrease the speed of debugging the app. Furthermore, the emulator will run much slower.

Comment: got your point. But how slow will it be decreased? greater than 50%?

Comment: Does it work on HTTP?

Comment: Say some path like this: 192.168.0.1/myfolder/android-sdk. May I give this as SDK path?

Comment: EveryServer have its IP or you can also give domain to your server. You can also find it in the network as i like seen in to the pic i have attached. Just select the sdk path from there and you will get it. And yes i dont know about how much it will be slow. But sure that it will be slow compare to local sdk path.

Comment: Does it work for you if you copy the sdk in all the computers. You won't need to install it on all, and it won't be any slower as well.

Comment: Yes. It is working fine. Even if you are using Android Studio and Eclipse in same PC and want to share same sdk for both then also you can do it. Its my personal experience. Please let me know if you are facing issue in that. Will like to help you.